# Two columns layout swapped in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word

My language is right-to-left and not left-to-right like English.
When I'm trying to use the two columns layout (Page Layout->Columns->Two), the first column (beginning of the text) is the left column and it continues in the right column, although in my language the two columns should be swapped.

How can I fix it and swap the two columns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this link at [Microsoft community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10/footnote-columns-in-microsoft-word-2016-using/2b7a9fb0-c759-4320-ab4d-b50af715e5ef)

1. Go to the Page Setup dialog
2. Choose Layout tab
3. In the Section part change the Section direction from "Left-to-right" to "Right-to-left"
4. Click ok

In my MS Word, I don't get any LTR or RTL option in the Section part, it could be because I don't have any RTL language installed.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 12):

1. From the Microsft Word ribbon (Menu), select "Page Layout"
2. Columns => More Columns
3. In the new window, check "Right to Left"

[image]

Comment: This should be selected as the chosen answer

Answer (score 0):

You should add language Arabic(Algeria)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2JYjNvvY4s

1  Microsft Word  select "Page Layout"

2  Columns => More Columns

3   check "Right to Left"